# FBViewController Use of undeclared identifier 'UIEdgeRectNone' on iOS7 Xcode 5 DP

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7

I have installed latest facebook sdk 3.8.Now when I am trying to run the sample app in Xcode 5 DP,deploymnent target is iOS7.Unfortunately I keep getting 
**Use of undeclared identifier 'UIEdgeRectNone'**
How can I solve this issue?
Below is the code snippet where compiler is throwing error:

```
   #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
   #ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
   #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_7_0
   if ([self.rootViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
   {
    self.rootViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout &= ~UIRectEdgeNone;
   } 
   #endif
   #endif 
   #endif
```

Comment: Why are you still using Xcode 5 DP, Xcode 5 is released.

Comment: @rckoenes I'm having the same issue but in Xcode 4.6. My computer is as upgraded as I can get it and I can't yet afford a replacement.